# QMainWindow opens from main() function, but not from any other function

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow

I am having a weird problem with my Qt app. I have a `QMainWindow`, conveniently `MainWindow`.

The following code works from the `main()` function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
    ..
    MainWindow mainWindow;
    mainWindow.show();
    ..
}
```

But, with the following does not show the MainWindow at all:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    AnotherClass::staticFunction();
}


class AnotherClass: public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
public:
    static void staticFunction();
}

void AnotherClass::staticFunction() {
    MainWindow mainWindow;
    mainWindow.show();
    return ;
}
```

Comment: i think you need to run QCoreApplication::exec();

Comment: While `staticFunction` itself is static, the `mainWindow` variable inside it isn't, so as soon as you return from the function, the variable goes out of scope.

Comment: Thanks guys, I just already figured that out! :)

Answer (score 2):

Oh my bad! Its because main never returns and enters the exec loop. However, since my function was returning immediately, the window was getting destroyed. Changing `MainWindow mainWindow;` to `MainWindow* mainWindow = new MainWindow();`  solved my problem:

Comment: No... I am overriding the `closeEvent` method, and destroying the window in it.

Comment: ok, you should mention that. By the way, you can just set the WA_DeleteOnClose attribute which will handle just that.

Answer (score 1):

In this code

```
void AnotherClass::staticFunction() {
    MainWindow mainWindow;
    mainWindow.show();
    return ;
}
```

The instance `mainWindow` will go out of scope after the closing `}`, and then destroyed. You will have to allocate it on the heap using `new` to have it outlive `staticFunction()`.

```
void AnotherClass::staticFunction() {
    MainWindow * mainWindow = new MainWindow;
    mainWindow->show();
    return ;
}
```

You will also need to somehow keep track of the pointer and having it `delete`d later (perhaps using a smart pointer).

And of course you will have to have a `QApplication` and call `exec()` on it in order to start the main event loop.

Comment: I don't think that's a very elegant solution. You are creating a memory leak.

Comment: @MrLister That's why I said he needs to keep track of pointer and delete it later. I agree it's not so elegant, I would have `mainWindow` as a local variable in `main()`, or as a member variable in `QApplication` subclass (if it is a complex application where I can have different main windows).

Comment: I am overriding the `closeEvent` method, and destroying the window in it.

Comment: @TarandeepGill if you're only going to do this once there's no point in deleting resources before your program exits (you will just slow down the exiting). It's ok to 'leak' certain single-application-instance things like the main window.